# Does android have a numeric keypad that is arranged like a computer's numpad?

Tags: android, user-interface, input, android-softkeyboard, android-keypad

I'm working on an android app and for some of my EditTexts I am currently using the input type "number" which displays a keypad with the arrangement that you typically see on phones with the "123" on the top row:

[image]

However, for reasons specific to the uses of this app, I would prefer a keypad with the style that you see on physical keyboards with the "123" on the bottom row:

[image]

Does android have a keypad that looks like what you see on physical keyboards or would I have to make a custom input method if I wanted to achieve this?

Comment: you can develop a custom keyboard and do whatever you want. arrange them like computer keypad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built-in parameter that swap "123" and "789" rows, so you have to make your own keyboard layout and handle the input.